# Laravel make:auth custom folder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

I'm new to using laravel 5.7.

I made a make:auth and to authenticate I need use http://localhost:8000/login and when I login I get redirected to http://localhost:8000/home, but I want login on http://localhost:8000/admin-panel/login and when I auth, I have to redirect to http://localhost:8000/admin-panel/home

Which files I will have to edit?

routes/web.php:

```
Route::get('/', function () { return view('welcome'); }); 
Auth::routes(['register' => false]);
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please post what you have done in your Web routes or look up routing in the Laravel docs for this answer? https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing

Comment: Does making a Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin-panel'], function(){ ... }) work?

Comment: Only work http://localhost:8000/admin-panel/login but when I initiate session redirect to http://localhost:8000/home. I wanna have an admin section on /admin-panel/ and change all controllers (change home for admin) like HomeController@index to AdminController@index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

routes/web.php

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin-panel'], function(){
    Route::get('/', function () { return view('welcome'); });
    Auth::routes(['register' => false]);
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');  
});
```

to see all your routes put this in the command line at your project root

```
php artisan route:list
```

Comment: now work if i enter or admin-panel/home, redirect to admin-panel/login and when i login redirect to admin-panel/home. But if a enter on admin-panel/login and login, redirect to /home

Comment: okay i fixed it, and how can i change all controllers? i wanna have a make:auth login on /admin-panel/login for administrators and another make:auth /login for normal users, when I create 2 make:auth both will have the same middleware? example: a normal user login on /login and auth restriction allow to show /home but too allow to show /admin-panel/home?

Comment: I think you should use the authentication controller to direct users based on "roles".  In the long run, this will give you great flexibility and clean code.  You'll be able to direct your users and guard your routes in a very clean/simple way from one login, one auth guard, and one users table.  I use  https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust

Comment: Then, I use roles and the login in /login and another login in /admin-panel/login (alone this one will allow to connect to the users who have role of administrator). If a normal user enters in /admin-panel/dashboard and role does not have admin that redirection to/admin-panel/login, this way would be?

Comment: Yes.  You'll just have to direct uses to the right place from either the /home controller or from the auth controller

Comment: And if i have diferents themes, where i can host it? on resources/views/theme1 and resources/views/theme2?

Comment: We should keep stack overflow organized.  Please mark your question as complete or answered ~ then start a new question for views.

Answer (score 0):

I think your intention is use prefix on route group.

```
Route::prefix('/admin-panel')->namespace('admin-panel')->group(function()
{                                     
 Route::get('/dashboard', 'AdminController@AdminDashboard')->name('dashboard');
});
```

After  this your route behave like this

```
 Route::get('/admin-pannel/dashboard', 'admin-pannel/AdminController@AdminDashboard')->name('dashboard');
```